# Select from database where there aren't any records since the last three months

Tags: mysql, database, adminer

I need to select the defaulting companies from my table (those who doesn't register a payment since october)

This is an example of what my table looks like:

| id | company_id | deposit_date | year | month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 578 | 2021-10-12 | 2021 | 10 |
| 2 | 254 | 2021-11-17 | 2021 | 11 |
| 3 | 465 | 2021-12-15 | 2021 | 12 |
| 4 | 159 | 2022-01-12 | 2022 | 1 |

**I must use month as reference and not deposit_date**

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'I must use month as reference and not deposit_date' - that's an odd requirement have you been told to do this for some reason?

Comment: I don't understand your data - are companies supposed to make a monthly payment or is the payment a one off?

Comment: Yes because some people pay months in advance or late, example:  |2020-07-07| 2020| 06, they don't care when they paid for it, only if the month was paid

Comment: monthly payments

Comment: Why must `month` be used and not deposit date? In all examples month and year come from deposit values. Seems `select company_id from table where deposit_date < now() - interval 3 month` would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for those where last payment prior to nov 2021

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id   int,company_id  int,deposit_date    date,year   int,month int);
insert into t values
(1  ,578    ,'2021-10-12'   ,2021   ,10),
(2  ,254    ,'2021-11-17'   ,2021   ,11),
(3  ,465    ,'2021-12-15'   ,2021   ,12),
(4  ,159    ,'2022-01-12'   ,2022   ,1);

select company_id ,year*100+month
from t
group by company_id
having max(year*100+month) < 202111;
```

Comment: I was not requested, but you could add something like `HAVING max(year*100+month) <= DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH),'%Y%m')` to have a dynamic query.

Currently, it would give us 202110 and each month it would move one month up. This would extend the result set in February for all companies which did not make a payment since November.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select and where clause to filter the data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).